# How to dynamically remove a resource and route from a flask-restful app?

Tags: flask, flask-restful

Adding resources and routes to a `flask-restful` api is pretty simple:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(app)

api.add_resource(MyResource,
                 'a_resource_method_endpoint/',
                  resource_class_kwargs={'param': the_param})
```

How can I remove `MyResource` and the associated endpoint from `app` once it's been added?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Dynamically add and remove these?

Comment: Yes, dynamically adding the routes and resources is not a problem, but removing them is more difficult.  I've seen the `resources` but I was hoping for a cleaner method to ensure that the correct references were removed from the correct places in the application.  Updated question to specify.

Answer (score 1):

Flask-Restful adds these to an list [called `resources`](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/0ec2edc63ea8fc4f50999cf98bdf90286173930b/flask_restful/__init__.py#L90)

I'd suggest you take a look at this answer here [to determine the best solution for you to modify that list.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

I do not believe there is a way to remove the items through an API supplied by Flask-Restful. You'll have to write a function to mutate that list based on some parameters.

I suggest iterating over the list once and removing all your routes at once: that way you save on runtime.